Teams displays messages twice in 2 accounts, how do I prevent this?
I use the new Teams and have 3 accounts. Some messages appear in 2 accounts, even though the person only exists in one account. What is the reason for this and how can I stop it? I don't want to always have to switch accounts to see the same message again on the other account. I couldn't find anything like this in the settings.
